Non-positive definite solution for differential Riccati equation
Consider the matrix-valued differential Riccati equation (DRE):
$$
\dot P_t +PA+A^\top P+Q-(B^\top P+S)^\top  (B^\top P+S)=0, \quad t\in [0,T];\quad P(T)=G,
$$
where all coefficients are  continuous.
It is well-known that if $Q-S^\top S\ge 0$ and $G\ge 0$, then the DRE admits a non-negative definite solution for all $T>0$.
My question is whether there exists any known condition such that the DRE admits a non-positive definite solution for all $T>0$? I am particularly interested in the case with $Q=G=0$ and non-zero $S$. Numerical experiments show that for some choices of $A$ and $B$, the DRE seems to have non-positive definite solution for all $T>0$. However, I am not sure whether it is just a coincidence, since in this case, the existence of solutions to DRE does not follow from standard results.

By "non-positive-definite", do you mean "not positive definite" or "negative semidefinite"?

Under your assumptions, the solutions is never going to be positive definite on $[0,T]$ for all $T>0$.

Let us consider the Riccati differential equation
$$\dot P+A^TP+PA+Q-(B^TP+S)^T(B^TP+S)=0,\ P(T)=P_T$$
which is the special case you are interested in. Consider further the Lyapunov differential equation
$$\dot P_u+A^TP_u+P_uA=0,\ P_u(T)=P_T.$$
Define now $E:=P_u-P$ and we get that
$$
\dot E=-A^TE-EA-(B^TP+S)^T(B^TP+S),\ E(T)=0
$$
The solution to that equation is given by
$$
E(t)=\int_t^Te^{-A^T(t-s)}(B^TP(s)+S)^T(B^TP(s)+S)e^{-A(t-s)}ds.
$$
Since $(B^TP(s)+S)^T(B^TP(s)+S)$ is positive semidefinite for all $s\in[0,T]$, then we have that $E(t)$ is also positive semidefinite for all $t\in[0,T]$.
This implies that $P_u(t)-P(t)\succeq0$ for all $t\in[0,T]$, which is equivalent to saying that $P_u(t)\succeq P(t)$. Since all the arguments are independent of $T$, then those arguments hold for any arbitrary $T>0$.

[This is work in progress!]
Now consider the conditions $Q=0$ and $P_T=0$. Then, we can observe that, in this case, $P_u(t)=0$ for all $t\in[0,T]$. This fact combined with the previous inequality shows that $P(t)\preceq0$ for all $t\in[0,T]$.
Under those conditions, the Riccati differential equation becomes
$$\dot P+(A-BS)^TP+P(A-BS)-S^TS-PBB^TP=0,\ P(T)=0.$$
This is the Riccati differential equation associated with the optimal control problem
$$
\inf_u\int_0^T-z(s)^TS^TSz(s)+u(s)^Tu(s)ds
$$
such that $\dot z=(A-BS)z+Bu$. From that, one can observe that in some situations, we would get that the cost is unbounded from below.
The change of variable $\bar{P}(t)=P(T-t)$ yields
$$\dot{\bar{P}}=(A-BS)^T\bar{P}+\bar{P}(A-BS)-S^TS-\bar{P}BB^T\bar{P}=0,\ \bar{P}(0)=0.$$
If we define the system $\dot{y}=-(A-BS)y+BB^T\zeta$, where $\zeta=\bar Py$, we get
$$
\dot \zeta=-S^TSy+(A-BS)^T\zeta.
$$
This yields the system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{y}(t)\\
\dot{\zeta}(t)
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-(A-BS) & BB^T\\
-S^TS & (A-BS)^T
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y(t)\\
\zeta(t)
\end{bmatrix},\ \begin{bmatrix}
y(0)\\
\zeta(0)
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
y_0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}.$$
The solution is given by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y(t)\\
\zeta(t)
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_{11}(t) & \Phi_{12}(t)\\
\Phi_{21}(t) & \Phi_{22}(t)\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y_0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_{11}(t)y_0\\
\Phi_{21}(t)y_0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since $\zeta(t)=\bar{P}(t)y(t)$, $\bar P(t)$ is bounded on the interval $t\in[0,T]$ if and only if $\Phi_{11}(t)$ is invertible on that interval. In such a case, we have that
$$
\bar{P}(t)=\Phi_{21}(t)\Phi_{11}(t)^{-1}
$$
and
$$
P(t)=\Phi_{21}(T-t)\Phi_{11}(T-t)^{-1}
$$

Thank you for the response. Do you know any condition to guarantee the existence of the solution?

@John You will need to be bit more specific. The existence of a solution to what interval? There will always be a solution an a neighborhood of $T$. However, if you can show that the solution is lower bounded on $[0,T]$, then you will have existence (and uniqueness) of the solution.

By existence, I mean the global existence on $[0,T]$. Are you aware of any results to show the solution of a similar Riccati equation is lower bounded?

I have updated my answer with additional details. Let me know if you have more questions.

I think you have assumed $S=0$ to get the zero solution. Unfortunately, in my case, the coefficient $S$ is nonzero. I have modified the question to make it more explicit.

@John my bad. I will correct that. Give me a bit of time.
